# IPhone says roaming data is turned off when it isn’t

Tags: iphone, cellular-data, sim

I am travelling in Europe with an iPhone 12 mini, with an eSIM from home (Australia) and a travel SIM from 3UK. The travel SIM has a 30 day life (for some resta il reason from the company that I bought it from). Last month worked perfectly; I could access Mobile data without a hitch. However when I put this months SIM in Mobile data no longer works.
I get messages saying “Data Roaming is turned off” but I don’t even have a switch to do this. The only control I have is to have Mobile Data Off, from the 3UK SIM, or from the Australian eSIM.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.

The switch wasn’t where it is on the pics posted, because I have 2 SIMs in the phone (1 an eSIM). The switch is actually at the bottom of the list of items detailing the 3UK SIM. See image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Turn on Cellular Data first, and the data roaming option is supposed to be located as follows (in "Cellular Data Options"):

[image]

Does this look different on your phone? If so you might need to ask your carrier if this feature is still active for your account.

Image from: https://www.ubergizmo.com/how-to/turn-off-data-roaming-on-iphone/

Comment: Thanks. Mine looks a bit different because I have 2 SIMs, but there is a switch specifically for the Travel SIM. doesn’t come up if you search IOS; would make it a lot easier!

Comment: @PeterGhys Did you find this setting and does that help your case?